# A create_or_get method in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I was looking if Django had some kind of `create_or_get` method but it seems that it doesn't have one. What I'm looking for the method to is that if the record doesn't exist, it is created but if it exits, it is returned.

I wrote one and here's what it looks like:

```
def create_or_get(self, url):
    try:
        return Host.objects.create(url = url)
    except IntegrityError, e:
        return Host.objects.get(url = url)
```

Where should I places this method, in the Model or in the Manager?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is already [get_or_create](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create), to be used like:

```
obj, created = MyModel.objects.get_or_create(keywordArguments)
```

Comment: What if I really want it to try first to create, to save a SELECT on 99% of my queries that I know that will be mostly misses on SELECT?